# TDE - Does Key Rotation involve full tablespace Decryption and Re-Encryption?

Tags: cryptography, hsm, oracle

In Oracle DB 12c, which uses TDE-Tablespace level. If i want to implement key rotation policy, what is the impact?
1. Is it the Tablespace key that will be rotated or the Masterkey?
2. Does key rotation involve, Decrypting the data with previous key and Re-Encrypting key with new key? If yes, would'nt this impact the avaibility of the DB in a production environment?
3. Should key rotation be done as part of maintainence period?